# Connecting Component VHD. RTL schematic does not work properly

Tags: entity, vhdl

I have made top entity which contains some others components which must be connected. I have been thinking where problem is but i dont know. There are no problems, warnings with code, just i cant see others components than clkdivider and vga(that can bee seen in rtl schematic). Any ideas? I have been trying to solve it on my own but i dont have any other ideas why isnt it working. In rtl schematic i can see that vga component is connected in TOP entity with clkdivider, but should be connected with others too.

```
 library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TOP is
Port ( 


          TOP_reset : in std_logic;

       TOP_clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
          TOP_PS2D : in std_logic;
          TOP_PS2C : in std_logic;
       TOP_red : out  STD_LOGIC;
       TOP_green : out  STD_LOGIC;
       TOP_blue : out  STD_LOGIC;
          TOP_hs : out std_logic;
          TOP_vs : out std_logic
          );
end TOP;

architecture top_arch of TOP is
component keycontroller
         port(
           clk25 : in std_logic;
            clr : in std_logic;
            PS2C : in std_logic;
            PS2D : in std_logic;
            keyval1 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            keyval2 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            keyval3 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
            );
end component keycontroller;
component Display_acc
         port( 
            keyval_in1 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            keyval_in2 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            keyval_in3 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

          ZNAK_Z_ROM : in std_logic_vector(47 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
       vs : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
       hs : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
       adresROM : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
          clk : in std_logic);
 end component Display_acc;     

 component VGA
 port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    hs_character : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    vs_character : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    reset : in std_logic;
    vs_out : out std_logic;
    hs_out : out std_logic;
    red : out std_logic;
    green: out std_logic;
    blue : out std_logic);
  end component VGA;


   component clkdivider
   port(
          clk   : in  STD_LOGIC;    -- sygnal zegarowy z FPGA 50MHz (C9)
        reset   : in  STD_LOGIC;    -- reset asynchroniczny

          -- WYJSCIA --
          clk25     : out STD_LOGIC -- wyjscie z sygnalem zegarowym o okreslonej czestotliwosci, tutaj 25MHz


        );
end component;

component ROM
Port (
        adresROM : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
     daneROM : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (47 downto 0));
 end component;
 signal address_character_rom : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
 signal data_character_rom : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0);
 signal vertical_synch : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
 signal horizontal_synch : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
 signal hs_output : std_logic;
 signal vs_output : std_logic;
 signal clkps2: std_logic;
 signal keyval_out1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 signal keyval_out2 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 signal keyval_out3 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 --wejsice tego co odbiera trzeba skierowac na sygnal wew
 begin
 blok1 : keycontroller port map(
 clr=>TOP_reset,
 PS2C => TOP_PS2C,
 PS2D => TOP_PS2D,                                  
 keyval1 => keyval_out1,
 keyval2 => keyval_out2,
 keyval3 => keyval_out3,
 clk25 => clkps2


                                    );
---------------------------------                                       
blok2 : display_acc port map(
clk => clkps2,
keyval_in1 =>keyval_out1,
keyval_in2 =>keyval_out2,
keyval_in3 =>keyval_out3,
ZNAK_Z_ROM =>data_character_rom,
vs => vertical_synch,
hs => horizontal_synch,
adresROM =>address_character_rom
);
-------------------------------
blok3: clkdivider port map
( clk=>TOP_clk,
reset=>TOP_reset,
clk25 => clkps2

);
----------
blok4 : VGA port map
(
clk=>clkps2,--25mhz
hs_character =>horizontal_synch,
vs_character => vertical_synch,
reset=>TOP_reset,
vs_out =>TOP_vs,
hs_out => TOP_hs,
green => TOP_green,
red => TOP_red,
blue => TOP_blue
);
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TOP is
Port ( 


          TOP_reset : in std_logic;

       TOP_clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
          TOP_PS2D : in std_logic;
          TOP_PS2C : in std_logic;
       TOP_red : out  STD_LOGIC;
       TOP_green : out  STD_LOGIC;
       TOP_blue : out  STD_LOGIC;
          TOP_hs : out std_logic;
          TOP_vs : out std_logic
          );
end TOP;

architecture top_arch of TOP is
component keycontroller
         port(
           clk25 : in std_logic;
            clr : in std_logic;
            PS2C : in std_logic;
            PS2D : in std_logic;
            keyval1 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            keyval2 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            keyval3 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
            );
end component keycontroller;
component Display_acc
         port( 
            keyval_in1 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            keyval_in2 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            keyval_in3 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

          ZNAK_Z_ROM : in std_logic_vector(47 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
       vs : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
       hs : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
       adresROM : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
          clk : in std_logic);
 end component Display_acc;     

 component VGA
 port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    hs_character : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    vs_character : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    reset : in std_logic;
    vs_out : out std_logic;
    hs_out : out std_logic;
    red : out std_logic;
    green: out std_logic;
    blue : out std_logic);
  end component VGA;


   component clkdivider --divide frequency of board
   port(
          clk   : in  STD_LOGIC;    -- sygnal zegarowy z FPGA 50MHz (C9)
        reset   : in  STD_LOGIC;    -- reset asynchroniczny

          -- WYJSCIA --
          clk25     : out STD_LOGIC -- wyjscie z sygnalem zegarowym o okreslonej czestotliwosci, tutaj 25MHz


        );
end component;

component ROM
Port (
        adresROM : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
     daneROM : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (47 downto 0));
 end component;
 --signals which are used to send data
 signal address_character_rom : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
 signal data_character_rom : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0);
 signal vertical_synch : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
 signal horizontal_synch : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
 signal hs_output : std_logic;
 signal vs_output : std_logic;
 signal clkps2: std_logic;
 signal keyval_out1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 signal keyval_out2 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 signal keyval_out3 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 --wejsice tego co odbiera trzeba skierowac na sygnal wew
 begin
 blok1 : keycontroller port map(
 clr=>TOP_reset,
 PS2C => TOP_PS2C,
 PS2D => TOP_PS2D,                                  
 keyval1 => keyval_out1,
 keyval2 => keyval_out2,
 keyval3 => keyval_out3,
 clk25 => clkps2


                                    );
---------------------------------                                       
blok2 : display_acc port map(
clk => clkps2,
keyval_in1 =>keyval_out1,
keyval_in2 =>keyval_out2,
keyval_in3 =>keyval_out3,
ZNAK_Z_ROM =>data_character_rom,
vs => vertical_synch,
hs => horizontal_synch,
adresROM =>address_character_rom
);
-------------------------------
blok3: clkdivider port map
( clk=>TOP_clk,
reset=>TOP_reset,
clk25 => clkps2

);
----------
blok4 : VGA port map
(
clk=>clkps2,--25mhz
hs_character =>horizontal_synch,
vs_character => vertical_synch,
reset=>TOP_reset,
vs_out =>TOP_vs,
hs_out => TOP_hs,
green => TOP_green,
red => TOP_red,
blue => TOP_blue
);
blok5 : ROM port map 
(
adresROM => address_character_rom,
daneROM => data_character_rom

);

end top_arch;
```

Comment: Why is all your code present twice? is that just here or in your original code file too?

Comment: Also what tools are you using? Ar you sure you look at the raw RTL result and not the post-synthesis result?

Answer (score 0):

If the RTL schematic is generated after synthesis :

The synthesis tool make a lot of optimizations removing your useless code parts. It can also include some code part from an instance in another.

It's depending of your synthesis tool parameters but usually it removes all hierarchy (components) in your design to synthetize a "flat design" then it rebuilds hierarchy for the user but the borders of your components could be at a different place or components could have been removed in post synthesis RTL schematic.

If you don't see some components, it doesn't mean that the functionnality of them is not here. Functionnality can be included in an other component (*VGA*).